# jquery time calculation - add hours on button click

Tags: jquery, time

**Hi please, can you give me some support with jQuery, I´am a novice and I can only do some few basic tricks but this issue is too complex for me.**

Basically I have two input fields with time format (ex.08:00, 19:00).

I have succesfully run the jQuery function which recount the minutes of the second field depend on first field. (ex. **button:45min** take value of hours from first field and add 45 minutes to second field so the result is 08:45). Actiually this buttons will rule the time duration of calendar events. This is already done.

**Here comes the chalenge:**

Than I need button with "hour value" which add 1 hour to event duration (ex. **start time: 08:00**, **end time: 19:00**, when I click on button called "1 hour" it will take start time value and add 1 hour, so the result of end time is: 09:00.

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="adds" id="30min" value="30">
<input type="radio" name="adds" id="45min" value="45">
<input type="radio" name="adds" id="1h" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="adds" id="2h" value="2">
</div>
```

Here is my Jfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/scree/g3WZN/4/

thank you for any help, I can appriciate that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g3WZN/6/

Basically you parse the first time into a date object, then add to it using `setHours` and `setMinutes`, then re-parse it back into what you want your format to look like.

Notice I changed the values of the radio buttons so you can specify hours and minutes.

Comment: you changed to radio buttons to specify hours and minutes ')

Comment: Ah, thats what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to gwin003 answer. Since I did the work, I'll post this here too.

I changed the radio buttons to be minutes. So for example:
for 2 hours you need to put 120 mins.

Also changed your jquery code to only update `input#end_time`

Updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/g3WZN/7/